# X DataGridPro edit one column in multiple rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am using MUI X DataGridPro to update one column of selected rows with a Dialog.
I have checkboxSelection enabled to select grid rows to be edited.
I created a Dialog that includes a form to update the boolean column.
I am unable to get a solution to update the grid upon close of the Dialog.
Tried using apiRef in the Dialog unsuccessfully (see below).  Note with this line commented out, the code runs properly with the exception of not updating the grid (without a manual refresh of the page).

Any links to a successful example of accomplishing a multiple row, column edit would be appreciated.

Tried passing apiRef as a prop to the Dialog to get the selected grid rows updated unsuccessfully.

```
for (let i = 0; i < props.selectionModel.length; i++) {
let data1 = [];
props.data.map(t => (t.id === props.selectionModel[i]) ? data1 = t : null);
let body = {
    id: data1.id,
    reviewed: values.reviewed
};
props.apiRef.current.updateRows([{ id: props.selectionModel[i], reviewed: body.reviewed() }]);
new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        axios.put(urlValue.urlValue + `/setAssetStigVulnStatusEntry`, body, options)
            .then((response) => {},
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
    }, 1000);
})
}
```

Comment: typo:  should be 'body.reviewed' only

Answer (score 0):

```
let data2 = props.data;
                         for (let i = 0; i < props.selectionModel.length; 
i++) {
                            for (let j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
                                if (data2[j].id === 
props.selectionModel[i]) {
                                    data2[j].reviewed = values.reviewed
                                    let body = {
                                        id: data2[j].id,
                                        reviewed: values.reviewed
                                    };
                                    new Promise((resolve) => {
                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                            axios.put(urlValue.urlValue + 
`/setAssetStigVulnStatusEntry`, body, options)
                                                .then((response) => {
                                                    },
                                                    (error) => {
                                                        
 console.log(error);
                                                    });
                                        }, 1000);
                                    })
                                }
                                props.setData(data2);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).